# Getting 0 in R instead of a precise result

Tags: r, computation

How can I get the actual precise result instead of the rounded ones?

```
result = ((0.61)**(10435)*(0.39)**(6565))/((0.63)**(5023)*(0.60)**(5412)*(0.37)**(2977)*(0.40)**(3588))
```

out:

```
NaN
```

Because, denominator is 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think ***logarithm*** is a power tool to deal with exponential with large powers (see it properties in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html)

You can try to use `log` first over your math expression and then apply `exp` in turn, i.e.,

```
result <- exp((10435*log(0.61)+6565*log(0.39)) - (5023*log(0.63)+5412*log(0.60)+ 2977*log(0.37)+3588*log(0.40)))
```

which gives

```
> result
[1] 0.001219116
```

Answer (score 3):

R cannot handle such large exponents because that will converge to 0 beyond its precision. Precision is not infinite. For what you want, you need an arbitrary precision package, such as *Rmpfr*.

```
library(Rmpfr)

precision <- 120

result <- (mpfr(0.61, precision)**10435 * mpfr(0.39, precision)**6565) /
  (mpfr(0.63, precision)**5023 * mpfr(0.60, precision)**5412 * mpfr(0.37, precision)**2977 * mpfr(0.40, precision)**3588)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
1 'mpfr' number of precision  120   bits 
[1] 0.0012191160601483692718001967190171336975
```